# PHP, MySQL, list records that aren't linked between 2 tables?

Tags: php, mysql

OK, I inherited a truly messed up database and have been tasked with cleaning it up.

The problem is this… I have to compare 2 tables. `table1` (members) and `table2` (associations) and find all instances of members that no longer have associations, and where associations no longer point to a member

The association table, `table2`,  has a field called `mbr_id` that, as you can guess, links it to a member’s `id` field in `table1`.

I am assuming I will need some sort of while loop…but I how no idea how to form the query. Something like…

```
SELECT * FROM `members2`, `assocs` WHERE `assocs.mbr_id` != `members2.id`
```

Is that it? Can’t be… right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be right is correct.  Try these two queries:

```
select m.*
from members m
where not exists (select 1 from assocs a where a.mbr_id = m.id);
```

and:

```
select a.*
from assocs a
where not exists (select 1 from members m where a.mbr_id = m.id);
```

The first is members with no valid associations.  The second are associations with no valid members.

Comment: Forgive me Gordon, I don't fully understand. What does `m.*` and `a.*` represent? And the `Select 1` only returns 1 record?

Comment: Those are table aliases.  In this case, they make the query easier to write and read.

Comment: Sorry... wife is in the hospital, Have not had time to work on this. Will do so in a couple of days... thank you in advance for the help

Comment: I am still having trouble forming the query. I am getting this error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource"

Code
`$userOrphans = "
 select m.*
 from members2 m
 where not exists (select 1 from assocs a where a.mbr_id = m.id)";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($userOrphans)) {
 echo $row['name'];
}`

Comment: @Kazigmal . . . Your code says `members2`, but the question says `members`.  I suspect you just need the right table name.